# Changing the view size of one specific layer on JS 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to imitate layerSwipe widget from ArcGis JS 3.x. So far I have come up with 2 options - one example works, but requires multiple mapView constructors, which is not a good idea probably, but other idea requires only one mapView constructor **but the option to resize the visible(seen on viewport) part of a specific layer**. Truth be told, I have almost no idea how to do that, so Im hoping for some ideas.

Link to the layerSwipe example from ArcGIS JS 3.x example:https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_swipe.html

So the question is very simple, so it doesn't require any code sample. Is there a way to resize specific layer(in current case scenario - TileLayer) visible view individually apart from other layers in the same MapView.

Comment: Here is source code for the 3.x swipe widget: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-dijit-layer-swipe-js

Don't have time to read through the whole thing but looks like it does a clip based on the swipe area to compute the area of the layer to draw.